# Insinkerator noise

Tags: garbage-disposal

I turn on the Insinkerator (garbage disposal) and it makes a racket.  Oops, there's a spoon, I knew this would happen sooner or later.  I remove the spoon and turn it on again; same noise.  This time my fingers can't find anything loose.  Did the spoon do lasting damage?  Is there a clever way to look for foreign objects in there?

Comment: The usual way of clearing jams is to use a HEX (i.e. Allen) wrench in the bottom of the unit to turn it backwards and try to free whatever is blocking it.  It's unlikely that a spoon permanently damaged the grinder, but it is a possibility.  Pull the rubber seal out and look into it with a flashlight.

Comment: Are you running water while it is running most require the water to be running when the disposal is spinning, I have seen all kinds of utensils stuck in disposals and other than the ones that the motor fried they all worked after clearing the parts.

Answer (score 1):

I would get a good flashlight and shine it bright down in there and have a little better look. Look closely, sometimes we can be surprised as to what we might find. It only makes the "same" noise as you described if there's something still in there.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't have a straight-line view to all parts of the interior, light or no light.

Comment: Use a inspection mirror and a flashlight. They're very handy when you need them.

Steelman 29 in. L Telescoping 3.25 in. Round Inspection Mirror Tool
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Steelman-29-in-L-Telescoping-3-25-in-Round-Inspection-Mirror-Tool-41820/303437614